# iframe element can't be align horizontaly with other content in a table

Tags: html, iframe

I did this footer which including a swf file, so that I add it as an iframe. However it keeps off set of the table. A link to my page can be found  [here](http://www.calibredesign.com/clients/spec/).

The spinning logo is the iframe window which can't be align with other images. Does anybody know what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `td` containing the flash logo has `margin` and `padding` set to `0` but the other `td` tags have `padding-top 5px;`

Just give that `td` a padding-top of 5px and it is aligned. (I would change the current padding to `padding:5px 0 0 0` since it's set as important and would over-ride a padding-top)